# How to test a helper method which uses a method created with helper_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, helper

I have a method in my `ApplicationHelper` called `#login_or_logout_link`, which just returns a "log in" or "log out" link depending on whether admin is currently logged in. The method which checks if the admin is logged in is defined in the `ApplicationController`, and shared with the helper via

```
helper_method :admin_logged_in?
```

`#login_or_logout_link` uses this method. The problem is, when I try to test `#login_or_logout_link` in my application_helper_test.rb, I get an

```
undefined method `admin_logged_in?'
```

So, how do I make the `#admin_logged_in?` accessible to the test when testing `#login_or_logout_link`?

I use `#admin_logged_in?` in both controllers and views, so it has to be shared.

Comment: What testing framework are you using? (test::unit / rspec / minitest)

Comment: The one that comes with Rails, I think that's `Minitest` (because it asked me to upgrade that gem once)